# Doubts in Python code

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm reading a book of Algorithms in Python, and I'm also new to Python.

I can't understand this example:

```
class Bunch(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(Bunch, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
        self.__dict__ = self

x = Bunch(name="Jayne Cobb", position="Public Relations")
print x.name
```

Some questions:

- What is the meaning of the * and the ** in the parameters "args" and "kwds"?
- What is the meaning of "super"?
- In this classe we are extending the "dict" class? This is a built-in class?

Best Regards,

Comment: * and the ** in the parameters "args" and "kwds"? is defined in the Python language reference.  super is defined in the Python language reference.  dict is defined in the Python library manual.  Why aren't you actually reading those documents first?

Comment: @S. Lott: +1 despite the fact that the lang reference isn't very approachable for newbies.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla: "the lang reference isn't very approachable for newbies".  I didn't find that to be true.  I'm asking a very specific question.  "Why aren't you actually reading those documents first?"   I'm hoping to find out why someone would fail to attempt to read that first.

Comment: Um, you should probably learn about the built-in classes and how to define functions before studying class definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*args` means: Collect all extra parameters without a name in this list:

```
def x(a, *args): pass
x(1, 2, 3)
```

assigns `a=1` and `args=[2,3]`.

`**kwargs` assigns all extra parameters with a name to the `dict` `kawrgs`:

```
def x(a, **kw): pass
x(1, b=2, c=3)
```

assigns `a=1` and `kw={b=2, c=3}`.

The code `super(Bunch, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)` reads: Call the method `__init__` of `Bunch` with the instance `self` and the parameters `*args, **kwds`. It's the standard pattern to initialize superclasses ([docs for `super`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=super#super))

And yes, `dict` is a [built-in data type for dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Comment: nearly right except that in your second example it throws an error TypeError: x() got multiple values for keyword argument 'a'

Answer (score 3):

1. http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions.  Explains `*` and `**`.
2. http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=super#super.  Explains super
3. http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict.  Explains dict.

Answer (score 2):

> In this classe we are extending the "dict" class? This is a built-in class?

You are actually extending the base `dict` [class](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping). This is a native class in Python. In previous versions of Python you could not extend native classes, but that has changed with [new-style classes](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes).

> What is the meaning of "super"?

The function `super` [lets you find](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) the parents of a given class, using the same order it would be used for inheritance.

> What is the meaning of the * and the ** in the parameters "args" and "kwds"?

`*args` is expanded with a tuple containint the non-named arguments, while `**kwargs` is expanded to a dictionary containing the named arguments.  It is [a way](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) to manage functions with a variable number of arguments.